# Is countable pointwise supremum of bounded functions achievable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $g(x) = \sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}f_n(x)$ be the pointwise supremum with $f_n(x)\leq C,\forall x\in X,n\in\mathbb{N}$. Can we claim that the supremum is achievable, i.e. $x\in X$, there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$g(x) = f_n(x)$$
for this particular $x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No: let $f_n(x)=C-\frac1n$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$. Then $g(x)=C$ for each $x\in X$, but $f_n(x)\ne C$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ and $x\in X$.

Comment: Can we claim that there exist a sequence of functions $f_k$ such that $f_k\leq g$ and $\lim_kf_k = g$ if we also have restriciton that $f_k$ is such as $\int f_kd\mu = 0$, for some finite measure $\mu$?

Comment: @Laimond: No, though the counterexample that comes to mind is a bit messy to describe. It’s possible to choose the original functions $f_n$ in such a way that for each sequence $\sigma$ in $\{f_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ there is a point $x$ such that $\sigma$ does not converge to $g$ at the point $x$.